# Give permission to user ONLY to install applications

Tags: permissions, accounts

I've been using linux for 6 years, but only now I had the task of creating 2 accounts into one PC. Those 2 accounts are Admin(Mine) and User(My Mother's), the problem is, when she tried to install an application Ubuntu ask for the admin password, but I want her to install and remove wathever software she wants but without all the admin permissions :S...

Is there anyway to do that ?

Thanks in Advance and sorry for my horrible english,
Luis Da Costa

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure sudo not to ask for password for any executables you desire for any non admin user you select. Following procedure would make sudo/gksudo/gksu stop asking for password when user named "User" tries to install software CLI way (apt-get) and GUI way (Synaptic Package Mananager, Ubuntu Software Center):

Open /etc/sudoers using your favorite editor, gedit in this example

```
sudo gedit /etc/sudoers
```

At the end of /etc/sudoers add:

```
User ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/synaptic, /usr/bin/software-center, /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Don't forget to replace "User" with desired non administrator user name. Good luck!

Comment: This does not work with 13.04, does it?

Comment: Didn't work on 19.04